# Python delete CSV row without creating a new file

Tags: python, csv

I am using Python (Raspberry Pi) to edit a CSV file.  I open the file with the "append" tag and add a line.  After that I check the size of the fil.  If the file size is too big, I want to delete the first row of data (there is a headers row).  Every example I see just skips the row and the writes all the other rows to a different CSV file.  I do not want to have to create a new CSV file...I just want to delete the first row in the current file and save it.

```
import csv

def write_csv(datalist):   

    with open("CSVfile",'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',' ,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer.writerow(datalist)

    while os.path.getsize("CSVfile") > 100000:
        ****DELETE FIRST ROW OF DATA FROM CSV FILE****
```

Comment: You will have to repeatedly save it again. Each time with the first row of datalist removed, until the size is below 100000.

Comment: This code has an error, there is no `writeline` for the `csv.writer` object.

Comment: Fixed it to `writerow`.  Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen how would I code it so that I write to a new file each time...yet the file name stays "constant" so that the loop would work properly if it needed to cycle through a few times?

Comment: You need to use a second file. You can create a new file and write to it. When the write has completed successfully, you would then rename the temporary file to the original name.

Comment: I wrote an untested example. The loop has been moved into `ensure_csv_max_size` so it's redundant in `write_csv`.

Comment: Perhaps you should **not** use a CVS file for your log. Perhaps you knew that Python ships with sqlite3?

Comment: Example is tested now. Mind the comments from @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the CSV is needed as the recipient has requested it be emailed in that format.  I am knew to Python and didn't know it came with sqlite3, so thanks for that information.

Answer (score 0):

Just a way to do it for inspiration. There is no need to make a new file and rename in this case:

```
import csv
import os
import random

def ensure_csv_max_size(size):
    # Read all data into memory.
    with open('CSVfile', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        csv_data = list(reader)

    # Remove first row, save, check repeatedly.
    for i in range(len(csv_data)):
        with open('CSVfile', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            writer.writerows(csv_data[i:])

        print(os.path.getsize('CSVfile'))
        if os.path.getsize('CSVfile') <= size:
            break

def write_csv(datalist):   

    with open("CSVfile",'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',' ,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer.writerow(datalist)

    while os.path.getsize("CSVfile") > 100000:
        print("cut")
        ensure_csv_max_size(100000)

for i in range(1000):
    write_csv([random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: And if the system crashes you've lost the file; and in addition this will ruin the sd card in no time.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala All true.

Comment: @totoro thank you for the example.  I ended up doing as everyone suggested and writing a new file then renaming it to the original one.  Didn't seem like the risk of corrupting things was worth it.

Comment: @Crewski Good idea. My answer was merely providing a generel example. I didn't have Raspberry Pi in mind.