# Unable to delete row with different table format in CSV in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am playing some data from [here](https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Okcoin_BTCUSD_1h.csv) in CSV.

I want to delete the "Timestamps are UTC timezone" and the "https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com" in the file. I've been trying to delete these items in pandas through `drop()` and adjust axis, label and some other parameters but no use. Since that row with those items has no label, so I can't really go through the label. I found some other posts to that need to create a list to process (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987312/how-to-delete-only-one-row-in-csv-with-python)), or go through `import csv` (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654791/python-delete-csv-row-without-creating-a-new-file)). But I just wonder if it's possible to do it through pandas? Since this will be a repeat process with many CSVs, it would be spending resource to go through csv package (I guess?).

What I really want to do is to delete the column "Unix Timestamp" and change the "Date" to "datetime_UTC" so that I can convert the datetime format in "Date" (it seems I can't use the name "Date" to convert the datetime format in pandas as far as I have done so far). But the "Timestamps are UTC timezone" and the "https://www.CryptoDataDownload.com" have been blocking to process the column deletion in pandas.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case of sample file it is enough to use keyword `skiprows` of `pd.read_csv` method

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Okcoin_BTCUSD_1h.csv', skiprows=1)
```

after running this code method `df.info()` renders following results:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
RangeIndex: 29650 entries, 0 to 29649  
Data columns (total 9 columns):  
Unix Timestamp    29650 non-null float64  
Date              29650 non-null object  
Symbol            29650 non-null object  
Open              29650 non-null float64  
High              29650 non-null float64  
Low               29650 non-null float64  
Close             29650 non-null float64  
Volume BTC        29650 non-null float64  
Volume USD        29650 non-null float64  
dtypes: float64(7), object(2)   
memory usage: 2.0+ MB
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well! Simple curious, what if I do really want to delete the row, the only way is going through csv package?